# How can I use my LG K8 as a monitor for my raspberry pi?

Tags: lg, hdmi

I would like to use my raspberry pi outside, which is only currently possible with the official touch screen. This is inadequate as the screen is a large unit and thus it is not portable enough. I would prefer it if the solution was wired.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile screen has not any video input port which can be accessed easily so you can not use smartphone screen as the monitor.

You will require HDMI to screen ribbon cable converter which is neither standard nor available.

**Edit:**  You can start a vnc server on Raspberry Pi and connect both on same network. [VNC viewer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android&hl=en)

Or Use mobile to ssh into odroid and for X server forwarding use [X Server XSDL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.org.server&hl=en) app

Comment: Does the VNC option require mobile data?

Comment: No, it only requires you to be on the same network. I am adding the relevant information in answer

Comment: Can this be done without an internet connection?

Comment: @LucasO'connor Yes it can

Comment: How is it done without an internet connection?

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer either use vnc server or ssh with x server forwarding.

Comment: How exactly is that done though?

Comment: Also by "no internet connection" I mean "no network connection".

Comment: Are you able to connect to Raspberry Pi to any wifi network with or without internet? If yes then connect RPi and mobile with same wifi and then type ssh -X <user>@<ip address of RPi>. After that open Xserver XSDL app to see the apps opened by the ssh.